# Is there a command encapsulating while+shift...?

Tags: xargs

My question pertains to writing a script that is likely to be used in conjunction with `xargs`. I find it cumbersome to combine an iteration step and a loop, when the second can be made into a command. I've got to be reinventing the wheel, so: what exists in this respect?

`while_do_it.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash

while (( $# > 0 ))
do    
    echo "($1)"
    shift
done
```

Can be divided into

`while.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash

command="$1"
shift

while (( $# > 0 ))
do
    "$command"  "$1" 
    shift
done
```

`do_it.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "($1)"
```

Application:

```
$ cat << EOF | xargs ./while.sh ./do_it.sh
foo 
bar 
qux 
EOF 
(Ctrl+D)
```

> (foo)
> (bar)
> (qux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with `xargs`, tell it to process its input one word at a time:

```
xargs -n 1 ./do_it.sh <<EOF
foo
bar
qux
EOF
```

But there already is a shell construct to process command-line arguments one  at a time, the `for` loop:

```
for i; do echo "($i)"; done
```

Comment: What if `./do_it.sh` took 2 arguments, and one wanted to keep the first fixed, say `blah`? (that's what motivated my question, I realize in hindsight).

Comment: If it’s fixed in first place, run `xargs -n 1 ./do_it.sh blah`. In other positions you can use `xargs`’ `-I` option to specify a placeholder, *e.g.* `xargs -I {} -n 1 ./do_it.sh {} foo`.